# How to have two commerce_file modules enabled and living together in a drupal site

Tags: 7, commerce

I need some `licensed files` saved in `private file system` and others in `public`, depending on my product type.

To get two [commerce_file](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file) license types, one configured to save the files in private file system and another in public, My easy and creative idea is make a copy (exactly same) of `commerce_file` module in a new folder and rename it with a new name. And replace all word in the files that have `commerce_file` word with the new module name.

Apart of this what more do I need to change in the code to have both modules enabled, and working well, living together without problems?

Surely somebody knowing the code in `commerce_file module` can answer this. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have two commerce file, why not create a helper module that have functionality that you need?

Comment: I don't know drupal module programming to program a helper module to get a second commerce license file type, then I have the idea to clone the original module and give it a new name to add another second license type file to my drupal site.